# How to display web site in top searches in a serach engine?

Tags: seo

Hi I want to display my web site and list it in the top searches in Google, Bing and Yahoo search engine? How should I proceed and what do I need to do(i can't spend money to promote my web site)

Answer (score 0):

### Google

Submit your web URL to Google's "Search Console": https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/submit-url?continue=/addurl

---

### Bing & Yahoo

Submit your web URL to Bing's "Webmaster Toolbox": http://www.bing.com/toolbox/submit-site-url

---

*Note: [Yahoo uses Bing's search engine database](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/business/8174763.stm).*